# Pandas Filter values by date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a date array dateref and want to get the values of pandas dataframe data
filtered by dateref (only the values for the dates included in dateref) :

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
  df: Out[36]: rec.array([ (datetime.date(2007, 4, 10), 105), 

  df[df.date== dateref ]
```

data.date   : array of date

data.value  : array of values

EDIT: this one returns error

```
data[data.date.isin(dateref)] 
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isin'
```

Comment: Can you add [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: data[data.date.isin(dateref)]   returns :AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'isin'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
data[np.in1d(data.date, dateref)]
```

Sample:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime as datetime

test = np.array([datetime.date(2007, 4, 10), 
                 datetime.date(2007, 5, 10), 
                 datetime.date(2007, 6, 10)])

states = [datetime.date(2007, 4, 10), 
          datetime.date(2007, 5, 10)]

mask = np.in1d(test, states)
print mask
[ True  True False]

print test[mask]
[datetime.date(2007, 4, 10) datetime.date(2007, 5, 10)]
```